# Get Entity from Path or Url Object Retrieved from Menu (Node or Page)

Tags: 8, uri

Linking through menu link tree elements I'm getting a series of url objects and paths. What I'd like to do is turn those url objects or paths into entities. I want access to the actual entities that they refer to. Here's my code so far:

```
$menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$menu_parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_id);
$menu_tree_elements = $menu_tree->load($menu_id, $menu_parameters);
foreach ($menu_tree_elements as $menu_tree_element) {
  $menu_tree_link = $menu_tree_element->link;
  $url_object = $menu_tree_link->getUrlObject();
  $path = $url_object->toString();
  $url_params = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput($path)->
    getRouteParameters();
  var_dump($url_params);
}
```

I was thinking that I could possibly get the entity from the url parameters but I get the error

> External URLs do not have internal route parameters.

Which makes sense to me because I have menu links that refer to just general Page entities not nodes. Like '/about'.

However I'm able to get to the paths just fine. Is there a way that I can load an entity since I have a url object that has a path directly leading to it?

UPDATE: I tried using

```
$params = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput('/about')->
  getRouteParameters();
var_dump($params);
```

But all that did was return an empty array.

I received the same result when using

```
$params = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("internal:/about")->
  getRouteParameters();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution by using the storage manager to load the entity using the path to load it.

```
$page = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('page')
  ->loadByProperties(array(
      'path' => $path
  ));
```

I'm assuming you can use the same method for nodes.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I'm reediting your edit to follow the conventions of the actual drupal core code. See the source code of the UserAuth class as an example https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserAuth.php/class/UserAuth/8.2.x

Comment: How should `$path` be formatted?

Comment: @Keven I believe something '/this-is-the-alias' works. Let me know if that doesn't.